# How to continuously change the property value of an object when a button is pressed in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, button

I am trying to create simple code that increases a number in a textarea each time a button is pressed. I have the starting value of 0 in a property of an object, then a function that takes that value and adds one. I understand that it will add one the first time and then keep taking the same value. So is there a way to continuously change the property of an object?

```
<script>
var myObj = {
    value:0
}
function addObj(){
    var numOfObj = myObj.value + 1;
    document.getElementById('textarea1').value = numOfObj; 
};
</script>
```

Comment: var numOfObj = myObj.value++;

Comment: var numOfObj = ++myObj.value;

Answer (score 2):

Balaji Sivanath is correct, but here's the explanation why:

When you call

```
var numOfObj = myObj.value + 1;
```

you are not changing the value of `myObj.value`.  You are getting the value of `myObj.value` and adding 1.  Since the variable never changes, this will always be 0 + 1.

By calling the '++' operator, you are actually changing the value, so

```
var numOfObj = ++myObj.value;
```

will  essentially run this:

```
myObj.value = myObj.value + 1;
var numOfObj = myObj.value;
```

**Edit:** Oops it's the prefix that does what I said.  [Here's a good link on the operators in Javascript.](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Operators)  Using the post-fix ++ will not change myObj.value.

Comment: Not really - it's a postfix operator!

Comment: @Bergi whoops good catch.  I changed it to the prefix and added a link.